# how to make an id in a realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a unique ID to certain objects to item information that I am inputting in the real-time database.

here is my code that I am trying to implement.

```
        database.ref('item/' + /*Here is where I would add the uniqueUD*/ ).set({
          ItemName: ItemName,
          Address: ItemAddress,
          Industry: ItemIndustry,
          Speciality: ItemSpeciality,
          Description: ItemDescription
        })
```

I am trying to have the database look like.

(ItemIndex) - (Item ID) - ItemName, ItemAddress, ItemIndustry, ItemSpeciality, ItemDescription

Comment: You could use UUID

Comment: @Andreas how would  i implement that in the code for instance ?  item.uuid

Answer (score 5):

Firebase will create an ID for you if you use push instead of set:

```
    database.ref('item').push({
      ItemName: ItemName,
      Address: ItemAddress,
      Industry: ItemIndustry,
      Speciality: ItemSpeciality,
      Description: ItemDescription
    })
```

See docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push

Answer (score 3):

A reference's `.push()` method creates a new reference even if you don't pass any value to it. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push):

> If you don't pass a value, nothing will be written to the Database and the child will remain empty (but you can use the Reference elsewhere).

This means you can create a new reference using this method without having to write anything to the db:

```js
const ref = database.ref('item').push();
```

You can then use Firebase's generated unique ID from `ref.key`. You can include this value in your data if you want. When you are ready to write data to the same ref, you can call its `.set()` method.

```js
ref.set({
    ItemName: ItemName,
    Address: ItemAddress,
    Industry: ItemIndustry,
    Speciality: ItemSpeciality,
    Description: ItemDescription
});
```

Comment: This helped alot

Answer (score 1):

2023 v9 modules syntax example of how to get the ID first:

```
const itemRef = ref(database, `users/${userId}/items`)
const addedItem = await push(itemRef)
console.log(addedItem.key, "This is the ID you're looking for")

await set(addedItem, {
    ...{ exampleData: 'example' },
    id: addedItem.key, // You could insert the same ID into the item if you wanted to.
})
```